# What does the ending of the 2013 film Enemy signify?

Tags: analysis, ending, enemy

At the end of the movie **Enemy**, Helen transforms into a gigantic terrified spider.

Also, there has been spider imagery throughout the film, beginning with the opening scene in the sex club, followed by two dream-sequences

1. spider-headed woman walking on the ceiling and
2. gargantuan spider crawling over the cityscape.

Is all this somehow connected?